# Is it possible to "install" a virtualbox snapshot onto a computer?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I needed to put together a local server, but before spending money on extra hardware, I decided it would be best to create a virtual machine in virtualbox to do a couple tests first and make sure everything is working properly.

Now that everything is working as intended, instead of reinstalling ubuntu, and all the required server packages, etc., is it possible to take the snapshot I created and "install" it on a fresh computer not running vbox?

Basically, I want to create a bootable disc image of the virtual box snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Download Clonezilla iso.

Step 2: Add the iso as a CD in virtual box.

[image]

Step 3: Start the VM and press F12 to open boot options.

Step 4: Choose to boot from CD.

Step 5: Follow Clonezilla instructions.

Step 6: Prepare USB drive when prompted.

Step 7: After Clonezilla is complete, remove the USB drive.

Step 8: Burn the Clonezilla iso to a different USB drive.

Step 9: Boot Clonezilla on the new machine and restore the backup.

Step 10: Profit.